# possible to set all elements of pointer to float after malloc

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc

Is there anyway to do the following in C?

```
float *t = (float*)malloc(t_size*sizeof(float));
t = {
  1,0,0,
 -1,0,0,
  0,1,0
};
```

Similar to how the following is standard

```
float t[9] = {
1,0,0,
-1,0,0,
0,1,0
};
```

Comment: C or C++?  The are not the same.

Comment: let's stick with C++

Comment: `std::vector<float> vec{
1,0,0,
-1,0,0,
0,1,0
};` :)

Comment: Since I'm already downvoted 3 times, I'd like to know for C now.

Comment: Out of curiosity if you know the size and all of the values why not create a normal array?

Comment: In C++11, you can do `t = new float [9]{
  1,0,0,
 -1,0,0,
  0,1,0
};`. Although I don't know why you'd need to use `malloc` before that. This is no placement `new`.

Comment: thanks logicstuff. if you post this answer i will accept it. (yes in this case there would be no need for malloc). do you know if c++11 guarantees contiguous memory this way?

Comment: i dont know the size of the array in advance. i'm parsing a 3d mesh

Comment: "possible to set all values of pointer to float" this title is misleading (and in fact nonsensical). What you are actually asking is if it is _possible to initialise all the elements in a dynamically-allocated array_ of float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As asked, a [c](/questions/tagged/c) soultion can be done using [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    #define  t_size  9
    float *t = malloc(t_size*sizeof(*t));

    if (t != NULL)
    {
       memcpy(t, (float[t_size]){1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0}, t_size*sizeof(*t));

       for (size_t i=0; i<t_size; i++)
          printf("t[%zu] = %g\n", i, t[i]);
    }

    free(t);

    return 0;
}
```